# (iOS) App runs fine on iPhone but immediately crashes in simulator, no diagnostic messages shown

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

My iOS app runs just fine on an actual device (even after hours of testing by multiple testers); however when attempting to run it on the simulator, it crashes immediately (doesn't even seem to get as far as `main()`).  It just shows my app's launch screen then immediately dies.  Absolutely no information whatsoever is printed or logged (I checked the debug window, the Console app, etc.).  Does anyone have any ideas/suggestions as to how I would go about getting to the bottom of this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details about this app?  Somethings crash in simulator because they aren't available like the Camera.  --Joe  What does you app do in viewWillLoad and ViewDidLoad?

Comment: It's an app for my podcast, <A HREF="http://otakunopodcast.com/">Otaku no Podcast</A>.  Doesn't use anything particularly special/exotic (camera, location services, etc.); just basic audio and video playback (AVPlayer and MPMoviePlayerViewController), also push notifications using Urban Airship, in-app purchases using MKStoreKit, iAds (ADBannerView), that's about it.  Also, the various libraries I use (tapku, Kal, etc.) each have their own test/demo apps that run fine in the simulator.

Comment: Turns out that my app runs just fine in the simulator if I run it in the iOS 4.3 simulator - it's only if I run it under the iOS 5 simulator that it crashes.  Weird, but I"ll have to live with it this way for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Reset the iOS Simulator if not working  Try enabling NSZombieEnabled

You can do by clicking on 'Product' in the Xcode top bar.
Press the option key and click on run.
Under environment variables click +
Added NSZombieEnabled and set its value to YES

You may find some error..

Comment: Tried all of the above, nothing helps.  However, I discovered (quite by accident) that if I run it under the iOS 4.3 simulator, it runs just fine.  Not really sure what's going on here, but I'll live with it this way for now - I'll just know that if I need to test against iOS 5, I'll have to do it with an actual device.